# Can I have two edit profile forms in django One is the main edit Profile form and 1 for just 2 fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a profile model which has too many fields. Two of the fields are `lat` and `lon` I use the django form to edit all the fields below

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    member_since = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    bio_images = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    activities_i_do = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    activities_i_love = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Below is the view to edit the attrubutes

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user.profile, files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user_form.save()
                profile_form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:profile', username=request.user.username)
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {'user_form': user_form,
               'profile_form': profile_form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', context)
```

Now the question is Can I use another form to just edit the `lat` `lon` fields of the above model example something like below

```
        <form method="post" action="{{ ??????????? }}">
            <input id="jsLat" type="text" placeholder="latittude" >
            <input id="jsLon" type="text" placeholder="longitude">
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

[image]

I have made the form with jquery such that when user clicks locate me the form automatically fills and submits itself. Can I use this form to edit just 2 fields of the profile model

below is my profile edit form

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm): #UserProfileForm or ProfileEdit
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('city', 'state', 'country', 'street_address', 'zip_code', 'phone_number', 'age', 'profile_image',
                  'bio', 'bio_images', 'activities_i_do', 'activities_i_love', 'lat', 'lon')
```

PS: The geodjango code is removed to make it simple. Just need to update `lat` `lon` as if they were regular fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed very difficult to have 2 edit forms for 1 object. So I split the `lat` `lon` and made a new model for it that

```
class UserLocation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

then I used the same HTML form above to edit this object details in the below question

[Editing an object with HTML form instead of Django model form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120434/editing-an-object-with-html-form-instead-of-django-model-form)

Answer (score 0):

You wont need to create another form. Since you did not show your form, I will assume you used

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'city', 'state'...)
```

What you can do is render the profile_form and use it like this

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ ??????????? }}">
        <input id="jsLat" type="text" placeholder="latittude" value="{{profile_form.lat.value}}">
        <input id="jsLon" type="text" placeholder="longitude" value="{{profile_form.lon.value}}">
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

at your views.py

```
profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST)
profile_form.save()
```

Hope it helps or gives you an idea! of course you will need to have some sort of primary key or ID inserted to the form so you can get the context of what profile to edit.

Comment: what do I add to the action field? I have added the profile edit form too. It is like the way you showed

Comment: That depends on you but again, I will make assumptions. If the "longlat" form is on different page to the profile form, you must create a new view that will process the form.