# Editing an object with HTML form instead of Django model form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to edit my objects using HTML form instead of Django model form. I need to know how to make the view for this (**See my incomplete view below in bold**)

**Intro:** I have a very simple html (invisible )form in the right column of my Index.html. when the user clicks on `Locate me` button. The form automatically fills the users latitude and longitude details and clicks submit(the user does not see the form). I use jQuery to achieve this

```
    <form method="post" action="#">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="jsLat" type="text" placeholder="latittude" name="LAT">
        <input id="jsLon" type="text" placeholder="longitude" name="LON">
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

[image]

**My models are**

```
class UserLocation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326, default='SRID=4326;POINT(0.0 0.0)')
```

**My incomplete view**(I need help completing this)

```
@login_required
def edit_location(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ??????????? #don't know how to call the HTML form   
        user = request.user              
        lat = request.POST.get('LAT') #lat is a field in the model see above
        lon = request.POST.get('LON') #lon is a field in the model see above
        form.save(commit=False) #Not sure if I can use this with HTML form
        point = lat (some operation) lon 
        form.save()
     return redirect("home")
```

Also in the HTML form `action` do I use the URL created for this view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a form in your view if you're manually picking the values from `request.POST`. Just create or modify a model instance directly.

You can create a form class that corresponds to the one you're writing manually to the the validation etc. when receiving data (but without using it to display the form). You'll likely need to add `{% csrf_token %}` to your html form if you do this (or mark the view csrf exempt).

urls.py

```
...
(r'^/my/special/url/', views.edit_location),
```

views.py (manually pulling request.POST parameters, and updating a model):

```
@login_required
def edit_location(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #location,created = UserLocation.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        location = UserLocation.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)[0]
        location.lat = request.POST.get('LAT') #lat is a field in the model see above
        location.lon = request.POST.get('LON') #lon is a field in the model see above
        location.point = lat (some operation) lon 
        location.save()
     return redirect("home")
```

form:

```
<form method="post" action="/my/special/url/">
    <input id="jsLat" type="text" placeholder="latittude" name="LAT">
    <input id="jsLon" type="text" placeholder="longitude" name="LON">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show me in code also. what do I add in the HTML form `action` If there is no view there won't be a url to add there

Comment: but you do have a view...? If you need to send the values to the server you'll need an url, and a view to handle it.  You can use post or get or ajax to submit the form, but one way or the other it needs to reach the server (and the only way is through an url).

Comment: I know that's why I have been trying to figure out how to make the view for this. Once I get the view. making the url is easy  `url(r'^location/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.edit_location, name='edit_location'),`

Comment: I've updated my answer with url/view/form that work together and does a POST-submission without using Django forms.  If you want to do this without a page refresh you'll need to do an ajax call from jquery and return a json response from your view.

Comment: do you think I will need to pass the user parameter in the url. I am trying this now

Comment: You don't need to pass the user parameter in the url (you've got it request.user), but if you ever need to implement impersonation (e.g. when your technical support guys want to view the exact same page as the customer) it becomes much easier to do with the username in the url and some permission changes (instead of asking the customer for their password so you can login as them).

Comment: I am getting a error `AttributeError at /accounts/edit_location/

'tuple' object has no attribute 'lat'`  I think it could be because the `edit_location` view and the html form are not connected. It does not know where to get the `LAT` from.  Trying to add the form in my index's `get_context_data` I am sorry How do I add this to my index's `get_context_data` usually I would do `context['form'] = DoubtForm` (from .forms import  DoubtForm)` How do I import a HTML form

Comment: @SamirTendulkar It's just because @thebjorn uses `get_or_create` so the result is a tuple, to deal with, you may catch all the values like the following `location, created = UserLocation.objects.get_or_create(...` or `location = UserLocation.objects.get_or_create(....)[0]` I edited his answer