# How to update a post in Django using the same manual-written form for creating it?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a form in which I can create a new post, which works perfectly. Now I want the same form to be filled when clicking on a link in order to update the post. I've found lots of tutorials, but all of them were using the form in 'form.py'. I don't have a form base on my model, I've created the form myself and now I want it to go to the same form-page and fill up the data, so it can edit the post.

When this link is clicked, which each post has one, I want it to go to the form-page and fill the form, so I can edit it. This link is in `home.html`

```
<a href=""><img width="48" height="48" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/pogchamp.png" alt="pogchamp"/></a>
```

This is my form. I use it for creating a new post, but I also want to use it for editing. It's `add_edit.html`

```
<form class="form text-center" action="{% url 'addEdit' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {% if messages %}
                        {% for message in messages %}
                            <p class="text-danger text-center fs-3 vov fade-in-up">{{ message }}</p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="mb-3 col-11 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mx-auto">
                        <label for="title" class="form-label float-start" id="title_lable">TITLE</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="U_U" required>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="col-12"></div>
            
                    <div class="mb-3 col-11 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mx-auto">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label float-start" id="name_lable">NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="＼(((￣(￣(￣▽￣)￣)￣)))／" required>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="col-12"></div>

                    <div class="mb-3 col-11 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mx-auto">
                    <label for="password" class="form-label float-start" id="password_lable">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="X_X" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12"></div>

                    <div class="mb-3 col-11 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mx-auto">
                        <label for="details" id="details_lable" class="form-label">ANY THING ELSE</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="details" name="details" rows="3" placeholder="(_　_)。゜zｚＺ"></textarea>
                    </div>
                
                    <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn col-11 col-md-4 col-lg-3" value="←">
</form>
```

This is my `view.py` for creating a post.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def add_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        name = request.POST['name']
        password = request.POST['password']
        details = request.POST['details']

        if title and name and password:
            form_data = Everything(title=title, name=name, password=password, details=details)
            form_data.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ("error"))
        
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'add_edit.html', context)
```

And this is my `urls.py` for creating a post.

```
path('add_edit/', views.add_edit, name='addEdit'),
```

So, as you noticed, I just don't know how to edit the post in the same form where I've created the post.

I tried this but it didn't work. Actually, it returns this error: `Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/\\Z']`

`views.py` for editing a post:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Everything, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        name = request.POST['name']
        password = request.POST['password']
        details = request.POST['details']

        if title and name and password:
            post.title = title
            post.name = name
            post.password = password
            post.details = details
            post.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please fill in all the required fields.")
    
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

`urls.py` for editing a post:

```
path('edit/<str:pk>/', views.edit, name='edit'),
```

And this is the link in `home.html`:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit' pk=post.pk %}">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure HTML to submit or update objects is not ideal these days. Nowadays, every form requires validation. You might specify a field to accept 20 characters, but end up receiving 100 characters.

To edit an existing object using pure `HTML` form not `django forms` you should provide us your view that render your model to the template, but since you do not, let's say you have a `MyModel` in your models files, and you want to edit an objects of that model, you should first create a view that display those objects via `for loop`, so in this case:

```
def my_view(request):
    my_objects = MyModel.objects.all()
    contexts = {
        'my_objects': my_objects
    }
    return render(request, 'my_objects.html', contexts)
```

After you created this view, you should create a template called:`my_objects.html` and pass `for loop` in it:

```
{% for item in my_objects %}
    <a href="{% url 'edit' item.pk %}">Edit item</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Your url should return a given error:`Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/\\Z']`.

your url shouldn't be:

```
path('edit/<str:pk>', views.edit, name='edit')
```

It should be like this:

```
path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.edit, name='edit')`
```

Your views is incorrect, you have to update it with this:

```
def edit(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item.title = request.POST.get('title')
        item.name = request.POST.get('name')
        item.password = request.POST.get('password')
        item.details = request.POST.get('details')
        item.save()
        return redirect('home')
    contexts = {
        'item':item
    }
    return render (request, 'edit.html', context)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120477/21835997)